# Array as cell formula parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I need to calculate polynomial coefficients in LibreOffice Calc to fit data points. X and Y values are in cells A2:... and B2:..., data size in in the cell D1, polynomial degree is in the cell D2. This works fine:

```
=TRANSPOSE(LINEST(OFFSET($B$2;0;0;$D$1;1);OFFSET($A$2;0;0;$D$1;1)^{1;2;3}))
```

I need to dynamically pass an array `1:$D$2` to this formula instead of `{1;2;3}`. I've tried to use the example from Excel help:

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & $D$2))
```

but it gives a value error. How to get this sequence in array?

Second question: if I'll be able to do this, how do I get the descending sequence `{3;2;1;0}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `ROW` generates a **vertical** array, whereas you require a **horizontal** array.

As such, use:

`TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$D$2)))`

Since both `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` are **volatile** functions, I'd personally prefer:

`=TRANSPOSE(LINEST($B$2:INDEX($B2:$B1048576,$D$1),$A$2:INDEX($A2:$A1048576,$D$1)^TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,$D$2)))))`

Regards

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can you answer my second question?

Comment: Wrap the Row part in a Large function with the exact same construct as the k argument

Comment: Or more generally, use this as the k parameter to the large function: `LARGE(MyArray, ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, COUNTA(MyArray))))`, where MyArray is the Row construct

Comment: This gives me only one max value... :/   Can you please explain your solution in the main answer?

Comment: Can you clarify that you want the sequence {3;2;1;0} and not {3;2;1}?

Comment: Array formula so definitely ctrl-shft-enter. Also confirm @XOR LX 's question about 0? You could add1 to the count and subtract 1 around a bracket

Comment: @XORLX I need to calculate polynomial values, so X should be raised to a power of 0....N. And `LINEST` gives the coeffs in a reverse order, `N, N-1, ..., 0`. This is not an issue, since as I checked, `{1,2,3,4,5}-1={0,1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: @MichaelO. So you need `1+$D$2-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,1+$D$2))` in place of `ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,$D$2))`.